# EthersJS Listening to events with NodeJS Strange Errors

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, ethereumj

I am trying to listen to blockchain events using ethers on NodeJS. I've looked around for few tutorials and copied the code from one of them. Currently the code i have is:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const usdtABI = require("./abi/usdtAbi.json");

async function main() {
  const usdtAddress = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7";
  const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
    "wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/api-key"
  );
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(usdtAddress, usdtABI, provider);
  contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, value, event) => {
    let info = {
      from: from,
      to: to,
      value: ethers.utils.formatUnits(value, 6),
      data: event,
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info, null, 4));
  });
}
main();
```

Link to Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GT_-jvSZIA&t=1s

The strange thing is that when i run this code on React project, it runs absolutely fine. However, on NodeJS, i am getting the following error:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WebSocketProvider')
```

Seems like on NodeJS, there is no providers class for ethers. But the WebSocketProvider Class is immediately exposed on ethers with `ethers.WebSocketProvider`. So i tried to use this instead of `ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider`.

After running the code, i fell like it is actually registering the listener but after few seconds, i am getting new error:

```
error = new TypeError(message);
                    ^

TypeError: unknown ProviderEvent (argument="event", value="{\"topics\":[\"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef\"],\"address\":[\"0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7\"]}", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.0.2)
```

Please note that the same code is working on React. I am wondering why it is not working on nodejs server side? Why is ethers acting differently?

Bellow i am attaching the steps i've used to create the node app:

```
mkdir Nodeapp && cd Nodeapp
npx init -y
npm i ethers
touch app.js
<<Fill the app.js file with the code above>>
node app.js
```

I have also looked at few github projects doing this, without any success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
    "wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/api-key"
  );
```

Try:

```
const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(
    "wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/api-key"
  );
```

The first was the usage in version [5.4](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/other/#WebSocketProvider). Currently the ethers Object have no providers element.

EDIT:

Version 6 is beta, it is posible that using the curremt 5.4 can help you to avoid errors. Please try to edit the file package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ethers": "^5.4"
  }
```

re-execute `npm install`

use again:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
        "wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/api-key"
      );
```

Comment: Hey. I tried this, unfortunately without success. I am getting the second error described in the post.  Here's the whole error displayed in the terminal https://pastebin.com/w5NV13wJ

Comment: it is weird, i copied your full code with my alchemy key and it is working here, i can see teh events, did you downgrade the version of ethers to 5.4?

Comment: at last, i'd try to change the ABI, the one i am using is https://pastebin.com/ifwy6cQZ

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. I've tried with completely removing the project and reinitialize it with ethers 5.4 and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works for me. Previously I was using ethers 6.0.8

Answer (score 0):

- and instead of :
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("HTTP://0.0.0.0:7545");

> do :

- const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("HTTP://0.0.0.0:7545");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).