# Call smart contract method with ethers.js version 6

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, contract-invocation

I was successfully using the version 5 of ethers.js so far and I'm now migrating my code base to version 6.

I tried the following code to call a method on my smart contract that is supposed to return an array of objects and it doesn't work:

```
        const web3Provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(
          metamaskProvider as any
        );

        const signer = await web3Provider.getSigner();
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

        const res = await contract.myContractMethod();
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what do you exactly mean?

Comment: It's working for me. Make sure your function name in the ABI matches the one you're trying to call

Answer (score 2):

Look at this topic.

[EthersJS Listening to events with NodeJS Strange Errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144381/ethersjs-listening-to-events-with-nodejs-strange-errors)

It's a very similar issue and it turned out to be a bug from ethers.js 6. It is still beta and not official release, so it might contain other bugs as well. I would say it's better to keep old version, at least till they release stable subversion of version 6.

Comment: Can confirm, also had couple of issues with the v6 beta. Went back to `5.x.x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
await contract.getFunction("FUNCTION_NAME").call(null);
```

this might help for ehters js 6
please take into consideration that you can replace null with an object that represents the call parameters, if any.

Comment: Does it return an array as asked ?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it's kind of weird and not very developer friendly, here's how you get your contract and print all the functions

```
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS,CONTRACT_ABI,signer)

        console.log("FUNCTIONS", contract.interface.forEachFunction((f)=>console.log(f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked.

```js
const signer = await getSigner();
const contract = new Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);

contract.functionName();
```