# Can't listen events with ethers.js, metamask and vue

Tags: ethers.js

I don't understand how to get events with ethers v6, I tried in this way:

```js
if (window.ethereum == null) {
  console.log("Metamask is not installed; using read-only defaults");
  const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
  // ...
} else {
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = await provider.getSigner();
  const abi = BiteIDNFT_abi;
  const contractNFT = new ethers.Contract("contractaddress", abi, signer);

  await contractNFT.safeMint("contractaddress", "ipfs://test");

  contractNFT.on("*", (from, to, tokenId, event) => {
    console.log(`${ from } => ${ to }: ${ tokenId }`)

      // Optionally, convenience method to stop listening
      event.removeListener();
  });
}
```

The nft was correctly minted on the blockchain with the correct Transfer event.

But on the browser console I get this `[object Object] => undefined: undefined`

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I report the answer of ricmoo that you could find [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/3838).

> You can’t destruct events that are emitted from "*", since every event
> has a potentially different signature. So you only get the Event
> payload, that object you are getting.
>
> So it should look like provider.on("*", (log, evt) => {
> console.log(log); }).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this topic:
[EthersJS Listening to events with NodeJS Strange Errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144381/ethersjs-listening-to-events-with-nodejs-strange-errors/144387#144387)

Essentially it might not be your fault, but a bug related to the v6 beta. Try downgrading ethers.js as described in the topic above.

Also one thing to note, you can use `contractNFT.once` instead of `contractNFT.on` and then removing the event listener. The first is more memory effective and closes the listener automatically after one captured event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The problem was the * param, see my answer :)