# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WebSocketProvider')

Tags: web3js, contract-development, ethers.js, websocket

I keep getting this error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WebSocketProvider')"

this is my code

```
require('dotenv').config()

const ethers = require('ethers')
const { BigNumber, utils } = ethers

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  `wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/${process.env.INFURA_ID}`,
  'goerli',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of ethers.js you are using? Try downgrading your ethers to v5.4.0 and check if it's working.

You can find more details in this post [EthersJS Listening to events with NodeJS Strange Errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144381/ethersjs-listening-to-events-with-nodejs-strange-errors)

Comment: Thank you, i will check out